# How to write unit test to Enabling Graceful Shutdown

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jestjs

Can anyone tell me how to write a unit test for this method.

```
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  mongoose.connection.close();
  winston.info('Gracefully shutting down server');
  if (c.getEnv('NODE_ENV') !== EnvironmentType.TEST) {
    process.exit(0);
  }
});
```

How I can test this code with jest?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract that anonymous function into a higher-order function that accepts all arguments that it needs to do the work and returns a new function that will be called on `SIGINT`.

```js
function closeDB(env){
  return function(){
      mongoose.connection.close();
      winston.info('Gracefully shutting down server');
      if (env == EnvironmentType.TEST) {
          process.exit(0)
      }
  }

}

process.on('SIGINT',closeDB(c.getEnv('NODE_ENV')))
```

So in your tests, you only need to test `closeDB()` function.